# Bulk Custom Menu and Wp-Ecommerce

Tags: menus, bulk, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have to add a lot of items in wordpress menu (lot of 2nd level items) is there any bulk menu item creation method available to do it ?

is there any way to add wp-ecommerce categories in wordpress custome menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto

> Appearance -> Menus

You can see all categories listed here including wp-ecommerce categories.

Just create a new menu for your wp-ecommerce categories. Lets call it "ecomcategories". You can call this menu in your theme using this code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'ecomcategories' )); ?>
```

You can just drag and drop for sub menus. 
You can create unlimited menus and submenus.

Comment: Thanks ! :D it solved , i thought wp-ecommerce doesn't support wordpress menus cause i couldn't see it in menu section , it was a unchecked checkbox in "Screen Options" .